# Probability of events: different formula for same operations?

Tags: probability

Which of the following formula for Probability theory is correct?

- $P(A_1) \cup P(A_2) \cup ... = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + ...$
- $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + ...$
- $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + ... - P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...)$

Please, provide me some references so that I can learn how to prove them.

Comment: Contrarily to what the pair of optimistic answers received so far state, formula 3 is wrong as well. For example, the sign of $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$ in the formula for $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)$ is not a minus sign. In the end, formula 2, *if supplemented by a suitable hypothesis*, is the less wrong of the three...

Comment: @Did The sign of $P(A_1∩A_2∩A_3)$ depends on the value of n given there are $n$ events. The sign is actually $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Aniket Of course (see my comment). Why are you telling me this? But if you know that, why are you telling us that the third formula is "the true formula"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula you wrote is meaningless, since you can't unite numbers.

The second formula you wrote holds iff $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are pairwise disjoint, i.e. $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.

The third formula is the true one, and it is known as the **inclusion-exclusion formula**. You can look it up.